# define nth function which will take an integer, n, and a list as arguments. The nth element of the list, indexed from 0, should be returned

Tags: f#

This is very easy but I am in new F# and still learning to define function in F#

I am trying to define nth function which will take an integer n, and a list as arguments. The nth element of the list, indexed from 0, should be returned. Any idea how can I do this? Thanks in advance

For ex : `nth(3, [1,2,3,4,6])` should return `4`

Comment: Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: let rec getn n list =
match list with
| [x] -> x
| _ -> nth (List.tail list)
may be i am completely wrong; i am still learning

Comment: can you at least show some code in another language or pseudo code with desired output.

Comment: this is what i was thinking: Input:  1->10->30->14,  index = 2
Output: 30  
The node at index 2 is 30

also the algorithm could be:
Initialize count = 0
2. Loop through the link list
     a. if count is equal to the passed index then return current
         node
     b. Increment count
     c. change current to point to next of the current

Answer (score 2):

Since you've explained in the comments that you just wanted to understand it instead of using a built-in function, here's my answer.

First, you want to phrase your problem in a strict way. In math-speak, if you will. Here's how I would go: when `n = 0`, the result is the first item of the list, and for any `n > 0`, the result will be the (n-1)-th item of the lists's tail.

Then you can translate that almost directly to F#:

```
let rec nth n list =
   let first::tail = list
   if n = 0 then first  // when n=0, the result is the first item
   else nth (n-1) tail  // for other n's, the result is (n-1)-th item of the tail

// Usage:
nth 5 [1;2;3;4;5;6;7]   // = 6
```

Note that this function is *incomplete*: it doesn't know what to do when given an empty list (the compiler will be able to spot it and issue a warning) and doesn't handle the case of `n < 0` (this one the compiler won't spot). I leave resolution of these problems as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think i have figured it out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Such a function already exists, List.nth is depreciated but you can use `List.item`:

```
List.item 5 [1;2;3;4;5;6]
//val it : int = 6
```

A shortcut it is `xs.[5]`, assuming xs is a list.

You should probably read the [docs on list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/collections.list-module-%5bfsharp%5d). And on another thought you should also read ["The Tour of F#"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/tour).

Comment: Thanks; but i was trying not to use any built in function and that was my main struggle. i wanted to take nth element as input and also the list.

Comment: @Medha that is very fine. But in that case you should probably make it clear in your original post that you want to write your own recursive `List.item`. :-) And it's probably better to edit your own questions with updates, rather than adding stuff piecemeal in comments. You could also examine the source to List.item?

Comment: Thanks. I am sorry that my question wasn't clear enough. I was going to edit it but couldn't find the option. i am new in Stackoverflow